# JSON.stringify escapes double quotes every time when stringified

Tags: javascript, json

I am storing JSON objects retreived from web service to objects in javascript. In many places this gets stringified(This obj goes through some plugins and it strigifies and stores it and retreives it) and it adds multiple slashes. How can I avoid it ?

http://jsfiddle.net/MJDYv/2/

```
var obj = {"a":"b", "c":["1", "2", "3"]};
var s = "";
console.log(obj);
s = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(s); // Proper String
s = JSON.stringify(s);
alert(s); // Extra slash added, Quotes are escaped
s = JSON.stringify(s);
alert(s); // Again quotes escaped or slash escaped but one more slash gets added
var obj2 = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(obj2); // Still a String with one less slash, not a JSON object !
```

So when parsing this multiple string I end up with a string again. And when tried to access like an object it crashes.

I tried to remove slash by using `replace(/\\/g,"")` but I end with this : `""{"a":"b","c":["1","2","3"]}""`

Answer (score 57):

That's expected behavior.

`JSON.stringify` does not act like an "identity" function when called on data that has already been converted to JSON.  By design, it *will* escape quote marks, backslashes, etc.

You need to call `JSON.parse()` exactly as many times as you called `JSON.stringify()` to get back the same object you put in.

Comment: Yes am doing the same now, calling it twice. But in some places its 3 or 4 times called.

Answer (score 28):

Try

```
JSON.stringify(s).replace(/\\"/g, '"')
```

Answer (score 21):

You can avoid that simply by calling [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) exactly once on the data you want turn into JSON.

Comment: Yes, but the original string goes through a series of function calls (in some plugins) and finally when its returned am not sure how many times it got stringified.

Comment: don't ever stringify it until you need to.  until then, just add data to a javascript 'result' object.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
s = {"a":"b", "c":["1", "2", "3"]}
JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(s))
```

gives the output as

```
'"{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]}"'
```

Comment: This gives `'"{\\"a\\":\\"b\\",\\"c\\":[\\"1\\",\\"2\\",\\"3\\"]}"'` in both node and Chrome console window.

Comment: Try : `console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(s)))`

Comment: that only goes one level deep.