# URL encode Nested JSON objects that contain url itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, url

So I have this main URL

`myapp://page/open-slideup-menu?params=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this._getDeeplinkParams()))}`

The `_getDeeplinkParams` function returns and nested JSON object like

```
{
      header_text: 'Post Options',
      cancel_text: 'Cancel',
      options: optionsArray
}
```

The `optionsArray` is as array that has nested JSON that can contain URL in them as well ..

```
    const deletePostAction =  {
      url: `https://api.com/posts/XXX`,
      method: 'DELETE'
    };

    const deletePostOption = {
      text: 'Delete',
      action: {
        url: `myapp://page/delete-item?id=XXX&action=${JSON.stringify(deletePostAction)}`,
      }
    };

    optionsArray  = [deletePostOption];
```

As you can see the options array has a nested JSON with URL inside of it.. I need to stringify the URL inside the `deletePostOption`..

But it stringifies it twice and produces an unparsable main deeplink..

```
myapp://page/open-slideup-menu?params={"header_text":"Post Options","cancel_text":"Cancel","options":[{"text":"Delete","action":{"url":"myapp://page/delete-item?id=XXX&action={\"url\":\"https://api.com/posts/XXX\",\"method\":\"DELETE\"}"}}]}
```

the nested second URL in the has \" in it .. SO that makes it inparsable..

Any clean way of doing this without `.replace(/^\\"g/,'"')`, so that all the urls are and deeplinks are properly encoded and it works for more nested urls

My ideal output would be something like this

```
myapp://page/open-slideup-menu?params={"header_text":"Post Options","cancel_text":"Cancel","options":[{"text":"Delete","action":{"url":"myapp://page/delete-item?id=XXX&action={"url":"https://api.com/posts/XXX","method":"DELETE"}"}}]}
```

Or if any other standard output used in production systems please let me know

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: This is my main try which produces wrong result:
```myapp://page/open-slideup-menu?params=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this._getDeeplinkParams()))}```

Comment: I tried using `.replace(/^\\"g/,'"')` after the JSON stringify.. but it seems like a hacky way of doing it so don't want to relly on that

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507858/json-stringify-escapes-double-quotes-every-time-when-stringified)